# Can't see properties from interface

Tags: c#, interface

I'm having some interface woes!

Here's the code:

I expected to be able to access the properties Added and ID through my test template, but intellisense says No!

Am I misusing an interface? Have I made a silly error?

Any advice appreciated - this is driving me nuts.

```
namespace blah.blah.blah
{
    public interface ITrackedItem
    {
        DateTime Added { get; set; }
        int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestTemplate<ITrackedItem>
        where ITrackedItem : new() 
    {
        public SortedSet<ITrackedItem> Set { get; set; }

        public void Test()
        {
            Set = new SortedSet<ITrackedItem>();

            foreach (var item in Set)
            {
                // cannot access any properties here
                // var ID = item.ID; <=============|
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public class TestTemplate<ITrackedItem>
```

You've declared a *type parameter* called `ITrackedItem`, which is entirely different to the `ITrackedItem` interface. It's not clear that your type needs to be generic at all - can you not just use

```
public class TestTemplate
```

? If you want it to be generic in a type which must implement `ITrackedItem`, you should use something like:

```
public class TestTemplate<T>
    where T : ITrackedItem, new() 
{
    public SortedSet<T> Set { get; set; }

    public void Test()
    {
        Set = new SortedSet<T>();

        foreach (var item in Set)
        {
            // now you can access any properties here
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. The former is the better answer to my problem I believe. The issue I'm trying to work round is the fact that I need to create a new ITrackedSet() at some point, preferrably without a parameterless constructor.